Ingress Redirect Issue for Prometheus and Grafana Services in Kubernetes
Ingress Redirect Issue for Prometheus and Grafana Services in Kubernete
Hi team, I would appreciate it if someone could help me resolve my issue. I have been stuck for 2 days, let me explain. I am trying to expose my Prometheus and Grafana services via an Ingress with the NGINX controller on a local Kubernetes cluster, but I am experiencing an issue with redirection to the authentication pages.
Problem Summary
Redirection and 404 Error: Grafana: The application expects /login but receives /grafana/login, resulting in a 404 error. Prometheus: The application expects /graph but receives /prometheus/graph, resulting in a 404 error.
Behavior with Single Path Configuration: When a single Ingress configuration is used with the path / (e.g., for Grafana), access works correctly, indicating that the issue is related to path prefix handling.
